# I can not search with the find () method in XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, hl7

This is my XML: monitor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ORU_R01>
  <MSH>
    <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
    <MSH.2>^~\&amp;</MSH.2>
    <MSH.3>hospital</MSH.3>
    <MSH.7>20170509090310</MSH.7>
    <MSH.9>
      <MSH.9.1>ORU</MSH.9.1>
      <MSH.9.2>R01</MSH.9.2>
    </MSH.9>
    <MSH.12>2.3.1</MSH.12>
  </MSH>
  <PID>
    <PID.2>SOPITA PALOMINO</PID.2>
    <PID.3>SOPITA PALOMINO</PID.3>
    <PID.5>S S</PID.5>
    <PID.7>19881107</PID.7>
    <PID.8>U</PID.8>
  </PID>
  <PV1>
    <PV1.2>U</PV1.2>
    <PV1.3>
      <PV1.3.3>Bed1</PV1.3.3>
    </PV1.3>
    <PV1.18>adult</PV1.18>
    <PV1.44>20170421</PV1.44>
  </PV1>
  <OBR>
    <OBR.7>20170509090310</OBR.7>
  </OBR>
  <OBX>
    <OBX.2>NM</OBX.2>
    <OBX.3>WEIGHT</OBX.3>
    <OBX.5>-1.0</OBX.5>
    <OBX.6>kg</OBX.6>
  </OBX>
  <OBX>
    <OBX.2>NM</OBX.2>
    <OBX.3>HEIGHT</OBX.3>
    <OBX.5>-1.0</OBX.5>
    <OBX.6>cm</OBX.6>
  </OBX>
  <OBX>
    <OBX.2>NM</OBX.2>
    <OBX.3>SpO2</OBX.3>
    <OBX.5>96</OBX.5>
    <OBX.6>%</OBX.6>
    <OBX.7>90-100</OBX.7>
  </OBX>
  <OBX>
    <OBX.2>NM</OBX.2>
    <OBX.3>PR</OBX.3>
    <OBX.5>69</OBX.5>
    <OBX.6>bpm</OBX.6>
    <OBX.7>50-120</OBX.7>
  </OBX>
</ORU_R01>
```

I'm trying to find the `<OBX.3>` tag inside the `<OBX>` tag, but when I use the find() method it does not recognize the dot character (.)

When I change the `<OBX.3>` XML tag to `<OBX3>` (without a dot character) the find() method recognizes the tag.

```
$("#btnProbar").click(function (e) {

    var TXT_URL = "http://localhost:44467/xml/monitor.xml";
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: TXT_URL,
        dataType: "XML",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('OBX').each(function () {
                var hl7_cabecera = $(this).find("OBX.3").text();
                var hl7_valor = $(this).find('OBX.5');
                var hl7_metrica = $(this).find('OBX.6');

                console.log(hl7_cabecera + ": "+hl7_valor +" " +hl7_metrica);
            });
        },
        error: function() {                                               
        alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
    }
    });

});
```

What method can I use instead of find() to detect the dot character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the regular expressions to fetch the xml nodes which has dot in it.

You need to change your statements as,

```
var hl7_cabecera = $(xmlDoc).find('OBX.3'.replace(/\./g,'\\.')).text();
var hl7_valor = $(xmlDoc).find('OBX.5'.replace(/\./g,'\\.')).text();
var hl7_metrica = $(xmlDoc).find('OBX.6'.replace(/\./g,'\\.')).text();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why use a regexp and not directly escape the selector? Seems overkill and dirtier...

Comment: How would you do it? @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: As per @Karl-AndréGagnon, you can use **find("OBX\\.3")**